# How to draw a path with rounded corners

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, custom-view

I should draw a CustomView like this shot.[image]

but they are not the same. corner strokes are different.

I use 2 separated `Path` to draw the top shape:
first one  for yellow background:

```
   private val paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = false                    // pass true does not make change
        color = Color.YELLOW
        style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE    // pass only FILL does not make change
        }
```

and the second is:

```
private val strokePaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = false                   // pass true does not make change
        color = Color.BLACK
        strokeWidth = 2.toPx().toFloat()
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }
```

and in `onDraw()` function I draw by them:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        drawPath()

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint)

        // at the end, draw text and default things to avoid overlapping with background
        super.onDraw(canvas)

    }
```

**Update**:
now I drew this that has 2 sides for its pointer.
[image]

and used this path to draw:

```
 private fun drawPath() {
    path.run {
        moveTo(left + radius, top)

        if (_side == SIDE_TOP) {
            lineTo(pointerX - pointerSize / 2, top)
            lineTo(pointerX, rect.top)
            lineTo(pointerX + pointerSize / 2, top)
        }
        lineTo(right - radius, top)

        arcTo(topRightRect, 270F, 90F, false)
        lineTo(right, bottom - radius)
        arcTo(bottomRightRect, 0F, 90F, false)

        if (_side == SIDE_BOTTOM) {
            lineTo(pointerX + pointerSize / 2, bottom)
            lineTo(pointerX, rect.bottom)
            lineTo(pointerX - pointerSize / 2, bottom)
        }
        lineTo(left + radius, bottom)

        arcTo(bottomLeftRect, 90F, 90F, false)
        lineTo(left, top + radius)
        arcTo(topLeftRect, 180F, 90F, false)
        close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Canvas` has some pre-defined methods for drawing common shapes like circle and rectangle. In your scenario, you can use `drawRoundRect` which needs a `RectF` to draw a rectangle.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
class RoundedRect @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val roundCorner = 32f

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.YELLOW
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    private val strokePaint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        strokeWidth = 4f
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    private var rect = RectF(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        rect = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, roundCorner, roundCorner, paint)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, roundCorner, roundCorner, strokePaint)
    }
}
```

BTW, If you want to draw rounded corners using a path, you must set `pathEffect` with `CornerPathEffect`.

Here is an example:
[image]

```
class RoundedRectUsingPath @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val roundCorner = 32f

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.YELLOW
        isAntiAlias = true
        pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(roundCorner)
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
    }

    private val strokePaint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        strokeWidth = 4f
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(roundCorner)
    }

    private var path = Path()
    private val offset = 50f

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(offset, offset)
            lineTo(w.toFloat() - offset, offset)
            lineTo(w.toFloat() - offset, h.toFloat() - offset)
            lineTo(offset, h.toFloat() - offset)
        }
        path.close()

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I want to draw via Path. because I don't want to draw exact RoundRectangle. (my shape is like message bubble)

Answer (score 5):

## I think I got a solution for you

It took me quite some time to figure out what's happening there.

> Note that my solution draws only a rounded rectangle without using
> path, but instead `drawRoundRect` pre-defined method of `Canvas`.

I was creating a custom progress bar which would have a border/stroke. The first thing came to my mind was to create a `Paint` instance, set the style of the paint to `Paint.Style.STROKE` and then draw a rounded rectangle.

```
override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    // I do the actual initialisations outside of dispatchDraw(). This is just an example.
    val paint: Paint = Paint()
    val strokeWidth = 4f
    val cornerRadius = 10f
    val strokeColor = Color.RED
    val strokeRect = RectF().apply {
        set(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
    }
    
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.strokeWidth = strokeWidth
    paint.color = strokeColor
    canvas?.drawRoundRect(strokeRect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint)
}
```

> *Note: The code above draws only the stroke, if you wanna draw the progress inside as well, you can create a new rect and set the style
> of the paint `Paint.Style.FILL`. It should be pretty straightforward
> to do it.*

### Well, this is what I get when I draw the progress stroke by using the code above, which does not look nice.

[image: Initial version of the progress bar with a stroke]

First I thought that the corners are not properly drawn and I should maybe increase the corner radius, but that was not a solution. After doing some research and testing different implementations I figured out that the issue is not related to the corners but the view itself. My stroke was just cut and not fully visible.

Adding [insets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF#inset(float,%20float)) was the key to solving my issue and it was pretty straightforward to do it.

This is the modified code:

```
override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    // I do the actual initialisations outside of dispatchDraw(). This is just an example.
    val paint: Paint = Paint()
    val strokeWidth = 2f
    val cornerRadius = 10f
    val strokeColor = Color.RED
    val strokeRect = RectF().apply {
        set(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
        inset(paint.strokeWidth / 2, paint.strokeWidth / 2)
    }
    
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.strokeWidth = strokeWidth
    paint.color = strokeColor
    canvas?.drawRoundRect(strokeRect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint)
}
```

I've added a single line only which sets the [insets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF#inset(float,%20float)) to half of the stroke width, which was the exact size which was cut.

```
inset(paint.strokeWidth / 2, paint.strokeWidth / 2)
```

> I've also modified the `strokeWidth` a bit for it to look nice (`2f` instead of `4f`). You can
> change it later to match your design requirements.

After that voila, you have the stroke which you would expect to have.

[image: Final version of the progress bar with a stroke]

I hope my solution will help you save time and energy!

Answer (score 2):

Just to create a round path one can consider creating one using,

```
import com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel
import com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearancePathProvider

fun createRoundPath(width: Int, height: Int, roundSize: Float): Path {
    val roundPath = Path()
    val appearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel().withCornerSize(roundSize)
    val rect = RectF(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
    ShapeAppearancePathProvider().calculatePath(appearanceModel, 1f, rect, roundPath)
    return roundPath
}
```

(fun fact, I learnt this from the same OP but somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that!

```
val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
}
val path = Path().apply {
    moveTo(x1, y1)
    lineTo(x2, y2)
}
drawPath(arch, archPaint)
```